# Rundeck API to upload job using python pycurl fails to upload file

Tags: pycurl, rundeck

I'm trying to implement rundeck job import functionality using pycurl in python, fails to find the file. Curl version of the same works fine.

```
    def importRundeckJOB(jobConfigFilePath):
        responseObject = BytesIO()
        rd = pycurl.Curl()

        rd.setopt(rd.URL, RUNDECK_API_END_POINT)
        rd.setopt(rd.HTTPHEADER, ['X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: '+RUNDECK_TOKEN,
                                  "Accept: application/json"])
        rd.setopt(rd.HTTPPOST, [("dupeOption", "update"),
                                ("fileformat", "yaml"),
                                ("xmlBatch",  jobConfigFilePath )])
        rd.setopt(rd.WRITEFUNCTION, responseObject.write)
        rd.perform()
        responseCode = rd.getinfo(rd.HTTP_CODE)
        rd.close()
```

Error ::

```
{'error': True, 'apiversion': 17, 'errorCode': 'api.error.jobs.import.missing-file', 'message': 'No file was uploaded'}
```

Working curl

```
curl --header X-Rundeck-Auth-Token:<TOKEN> -F xmlBatch=@"<FILE_PATH>"  -F dupeOption=update -F fileformat=yaml <RUNDECK_API_END_POINT>/import

{
  "succeeded": [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "id": "deploy-job",
      "name": "deploy-job",
      "group": "DEV",
      "project": "SOF",
      "permalink": "<RUNDECK_URL>/job/show/deploy-job"
    }
  ],
  "failed": [],
  "skipped": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found a solution, i need to an additional parameter to handle files.

http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html#file-upload-multipart-post

```
c.FORM_FILE
```

Working solution

```
    def importRundeckJOB(jobConfigFilePath):
        responseObject = BytesIO()
        rd = pycurl.Curl()

        rd.setopt(rd.URL, RUNDECK_API_END_POINT)
        rd.setopt(rd.HTTPHEADER, ['X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: '+RUNDECK_TOKEN,
                                  "Accept: application/json"])
        rd.setopt(rd.HTTPPOST, [("dupeOption", "update"),
                                ("fileformat", "yaml"),
                                ("xmlBatch",  (rd.FORM_FILE, jobConfigFile))])
        rd.setopt(rd.WRITEFUNCTION, responseObject.write)
        rd.perform()
        responseCode = rd.getinfo(rd.HTTP_CODE)
        rd.close()
```